# Jquery.cookie возвращает СТРОКУ [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Хочу получить определенную cookie, возвращается строка [object Object], не объект. Там видимо сам jquery.cookie toString делает. В самом значении куки именно строка, но самих кук с таким названием несколько, они на разные path записаны, видимо из-за этого и object. Возможно ли как-то это поправить? Может я могу получить все значения кук, если jquery.cookie не будет делать toString? или может я могу ограничить path только с /path, что бы он не брал с /path/path/path и.т.д ?

Вот мой код:

```
$.cookie.defaults.path = '/ec2';
$(function(){
     var obj = $.cookie('f5avrbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', { path: '/ec2' });
     console.log(typeof obj);
}
```

Comment: кука ставится только как string, а вы пытаетесь объект записать. `JSON.stringify(my_var)` когда ставите, `JSON.parse(cookie)` когда читаете

Comment: куку ставлю не я, я с другого сайта через плагин пытаюсь взять. И внутри неё не объект а строка, просто самих кук с таким названием несколько. Прочитайте пожалуйста ещё раз пост

Comment: Приветдите пожалуйста, пример кук. Взять можно вот так `document.cookie`. И сообщите название куки, которая нужна.

Comment: Конечно. Вот пример: http://prntscr.com/jouq9e . Через document.cookie взять не могу, потому что другой path

Comment: Надо ставить на корневой (`/`) path куку, и тогда отовсюду с ней сможете работать. Но куку, который поставил другой домен вы взять не можете, и плагины никакие не помогут.

Comment: Дело не в другом домене, куку то я могу взять. Всё хорошо, просто их много и возвращается [object Object]

Comment: Добавил свой код в пост

Comment: Так куки устанавливаются на другом домене? Если так, то прав @ArtemGorlachev. Никак вы эти куки не получите.

Comment: `document.cookie` - получите все значения кук. JQuery их просто перерабатывает в более удобный вид. http://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: Я понял, почему куки нет в document.cookie и в $.cookie(). Просто странная защита на сайте после использования сразу её удаляет. Может можно как-то получить удаленную куку?